load gml with gdal org driver (with driver options) in c#
I try to open a wfs gml file with gdal and I want to use the options DOWNLOAD_SCHEMA and GML_SKIP_RESOLVE_ELEMS.
But when I use the GML Driver, I couldn't find a way to add options.
public GMLFile(string fullPathGml, bool deleteTempFiles = true)
{
    var options = new string[]
    {
        "DOWNLOAD_SCHEMA=NO",
        "GML_SKIP_RESOLVE_ELEMS=ALL"
    };

    var drv = Ogr.GetDriverByName("GML");
   
    DataSource = drv.Open(fullPathGml, 0);
}

When I use Gdal.OpenEx() I will get a Dataset, but I need a Datasource.
How can I solve this problem?
